# will older android devices crash with canRequestFilterKeyEvents

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I want to use [canRequestFilterKeyEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html) option in my accessibility service enabled app. I get a warning saying that this is supported only from API level 18 and my app minimum API is 14.

I am ok, if the features I enable using this setting is not available for users below API level 18. But i want to make sure the app would not crash in older version because this setting is enabled.

I have this setting enable in accessibility_service_config.xml file. I have given the full config below.

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackVisual"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not crash the application because `android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents` will not be parsed in code on pre API 18 phones. So it should be save put it there. If it somehow does crash your app you could also make 2 xml folders one named just xml and the other xml-v18

Comment: my xml folder is named as "xml". should i rename it to "raw" or "xml-v18" would work as well?

Comment: no you can use folder qualifiers -v18 everything inside will only be used in API 18 and up. this goes for als resource folders strings/layout/values etc. But as I said in my answer it should not crash your app.

Comment: But since your answer is uncertain and giving me an alternate, i feel its better i go with folder qualifiers approach

Comment: can you also look at my other question and see if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919396/get-share-content-through-accessibility-in-android-app