# Disconnect a call programatically not working in android 8.0(Oreo)

Tags: android, android-permissions, telephonymanager, android-phone-call

Up to Android 7.1 it was possible to end an incoming call by using the ITelephony.endCall() method and giving your app the permissions android.permission.CALL_PHONE and android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

When doing the same on Android 8.0 Oreo (API 26), i get this error

> 12-14 17:37:26.160 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 12-14 17:37:26.161
>   20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 12-14 17:37:26.161
>   20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   com.xinthe.carmode.listeners.MyPhoneStateListener.disconnectCall(MyPhoneStateListener.java:108)
>   12-14 17:37:26.161 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   com.xinthe.carmode.listeners.MyPhoneStateListener.onCallStateChanged(MyPhoneStateListener.java:51)
>   12-14 17:37:26.161 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:338)
>   12-14 17:37:26.161 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 12-14
>   17:37:26.161 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 12-14 17:37:26.161
>   20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 12-14
>   17:37:26.161 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 12-14 17:37:26.161
>   20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   12-14 17:37:26.161 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 12-14
>   17:37:26.162 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err: Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10304 nor current process
>   has android.permission.CALL_PHONE. 12-14 17:37:26.162
>   20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942) 12-14 17:37:26.162
>   20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888) 12-14 17:37:26.162
>   20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.endCall(ITelephony.java:1955)
>   12-14 17:37:26.162 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode W/System.err:   ...
>   10 more 12-14 17:37:26.162 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode
>   E/End call error: FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony
>   subsystem 12-14 17:37:26.162 20962-20962/com.xinthe.carmode
>   E/End call error: Exception object:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Here is the code for READ_PHONE_STATE run time permission.

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS};
void permissionCheck() {

    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
}

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Looks like you relied on an undocumented method that you called through reflection. What you did was not intended to be done by the Android team, and they most likely just stuffed that security hole.

Comment: show me your code where you add runtime permissionws

Comment: @WaleedAsim updated the question with run time permission code. Please check.

Comment: is it triggered when you run application?

Comment: Yes.It will trigger from oncreate

Comment: try this code below marshmellow version

Comment: you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731725/how-to-end-an-incoming-call-programmatically-on-android-8-0-oreo/57356900#57356900

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you forgot adding runtime permission for CALL_PHONE
**Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10304 nor current process has android.permission.CALL_PHONE.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I added


String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }

Comment: But... `CALL_PHONE` isn't in your list...

Comment: This was exactly my issue , many thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is via Android Accessibility Service.
You can find the resource id of Cancel call button and Click that via 11y Service!

Check out this link which uses Android Accessibility Service to press "Force Stop" button just like Greenify App.

[How to click button in settings using AccessibilityService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628262/how-to-click-button-in-settings-using-accessibilityservice/26687754)

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you give little more explanation or else send reference links please.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628262/how-to-click-button-in-settings-using-accessibilityservice/26687754